# Sending a String of Data to a Specific Client

Tags: c#, string, listview, connection, client-server

This could be a very hard question.. But here we go, so I have a Multi Client chat server, I handle the Multi - Client part with a new Class called ClientConnection, everytime a client connects, it creates a new instance of ClientConnection for that client, and incoming data is handled in that client's class. When a new client connects, it is added to a listView on my admin panel, now, I want to be able to boot a specific client from the server. I want to right click his IP and click boot. (The right click and menu are done and in place). I currently have this:

```
private void cMDToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        foreach(ListViewItem LIST_ITEM in listView1.Items)
        {
            ClientConnection SPEC_client = (ClientConnection)LIST_ITEM.Tag;
        }


}
```

But I have a feeling it will just loop through ALL clients and kick all of them, which I don't want. How can I send data to just one?

Comment: Have you seen `ListView.SelectedItems` property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, but how can I link it to Sending data to it?

Comment: The same way you doing it with `listView1.Items` - `SelectedItems` it's just a collection of `ListViewItem` objects.

Comment: Hmm... Yes, but how can I tell the StreamWriter to write it to that client?

Comment: I have no idea, what your `ClientConnection` type is. It is not clear, what is your question about - UI interaction (get the selected item and its contextual data), or communication aspects (after get the contextual data, how to send something to client).

Comment: Here is a complete explanation, it holds delegate voids for invoking client received and client disconnected, reads data from the client it is assigned to and sends data to the client it is assigned to. I want to be able to send data to it from right clicking on it's IP in listView

Comment: Separate your problem into two parts. First identify which ClientConnection you want to boot (use SelectedItems as Dennis suggested) - and then have a public method in ClientConnection called "Disconnect" or similar to force closure of the socket.